# Use variables from a callback function into loop process of another callback function...Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, promise, blogger

I have the "favouritePosts" json callback function working with blogger feed:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        //<![CDATA[ 

          function favouritePosts(json) {

          for (var i = 0; i < numposts; i++) {
            var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
            var posttitle = entry.title.$t;
            var posturl;
            postdate = entry.published.$t;
            var post_id = i;
            var postThumb = entry.media$thumbnail.url;
            var authorname = entry.author[0].name.$t; 
            var author_img = entry.author[0].gd$image.src;  
            var author_uri = entry.author[0].uri.$t;
            var label_category = entry.category[i].term;


        var item = '<a class="listing-geodir-category" href="">'+label_category+'</a><a href="'+author_uri+'"></a><span class="avatar-tooltip">Added By  <strong>'+authorname+'</strong></span></div><h3><a href="'+posturl+'">'+posttitle+'</a></h3><div class="geodir-category-options fl-wrap"></div></div>';
        document.write(item);
        }
}
 //]]>
 </script>
```

that is called with the following script

```
<script src='/feeds/posts/summary/-/Νέα%20Καταχώρηση?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=favouritePosts'/>
```

Also there is "displayContent" json callback function that is working with sheets api:

```
<script>
 //<![CDATA[ 

  function displayContent(json) {
         var string = "";      
            var len = json.feed.entry.length;
            for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
                  var user = json.feed.entry[i].gsx$user.$t;
                  var comment = json.feed.entry[i].gsx$comment.$t;
                  var rating = json.feed.entry[i].gsx$rating.$t;
                  var date = json.feed.entry[i].gsx$date.$t;



                  string += '<div class="reviews-comments-item"><div class="reviews-comments-item-text"><h4><a href="#">' + user + '</a></h4><div class="listing-rating card-popup-rainingvis" data-starrating2="'+rating+'"></div><div class="clearfix"></div><p>"' + comment + '"</p><span class="reviews-comments-item-date"><i class="fas fa-calendar-check"></i>'+date+'</span></div></div>';
            }


            $(string).appendTo('div.reviews-comments-wrap');
        }   
//]]>

        </script>
```

and is called with

```
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/____/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=displayContent">;</script>
```

Is it possible to get variables that used into "displayContent" sheets api json callback and use them into "favouriteposts" callback function?

Maybe with a promise function???

Comment: Can't really tell what you're asking.

Comment: In blogger feed api you can via callback to get post url, post title, post image from a number of posts, depending on label of posts.

Comment: That I want is to save  into a Google spreadsheet post ratings into a column and after that with a way to get via blogger feed callback function information about the rating of the post

Comment: You could try this with the [Blogger](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/get) and [Sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/) API.

Comment: @jfriend00 why you can't?

Comment: @Jescanellas how? do you have any idea?

Comment: I know that in blogger JSON callback function you can add a function in var item and passion it a dynamic variable...for example '+display content()+'